# Как использовать поток несколько раз?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть программа, где выполняется последовательное рисование картинки - наподобие анимации.

```
//------------
public void paint (Graphics g){
    g = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (p.dx==1&&!k){     
        k=true;            
        ani.start(); // ani - это поток
        }
     }
//---
public void run() {
    boolean l=false;
    while(l==false){
       p.move();
       try {
         ani.sleep(10);
       catch{//обработка исключения  }
     }
}
```

Здесь при нажатии клавиши запускаем поток, который каждые 10мс меняет координаты изображения. Но есть одна проблема. В таком виде поток выполнится всего 1 раз, а потом выкинится ошибка. Если в метод `paint()` перед стартом потока вписать `ani= new Thread(this)`, то все будет работать, но создаться куча потоков, что соответственно будет сказываться на скорости работы.

Как после работы потока его остановить а потом ,когда надо будет, запустить его методом `.start()` ?

Comment: один объект потока можно запустить только один раз. читайте пожалуйста книги или мануалы, это написано сразу же в главе о состояниях потока.

Comment: ой как плохо получилось(( 

Я просто запустил программу в NetBeans'е в режиме отладки, и он показал мне что выполняется Thread-1, потом Thread-2 и так далее. На Thread-143 мне стало страшно. Я подумал что он создает кучу потоков, которые много кушают)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поток выполняется 1 раз, как пишется в документации:

> It is never legal to start a thread
> more than once. In particular, a
> thread may not be restarted once it
> has completed execution.

Именно поэтому у вас выкидывается исключение - очевидно `IllegalThreadStateException`, которое как раз и выкидывается при попытке повторного запуска треда.

В общем надо каждый раз создавать новый объект `Thread`.

Много тредов создается потому, что они у вас не останавливаются, а останавливается тред при окончании цикла в `run()` - подумайте как его вам останавливать, то есть где-то он должен получить `l=true`

Answer (score 2):

В цикле while нужно сделать проверку !Thread.isInterrupted(), а в методе paint прервать текущий поток вызвав у него interrupt(), после чего дождаться его завершения join(). Когда поток остановился, создать новый и вызвать на нем start(). Как то так:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (p.dx == 1 && !k) {
            k = true;
            ani.interrupt();
            ani.join();

            ani=//создание нового потока
            ani.start(); // ani - это поток
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            p.move();
            try {
                ani.sleep(10);
            }catch{//обработка исключения  }
                }
        }
    }
```