# Java. Многопоточность. Использование существующих потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пишу простую программу, она должно создавать необходимое пользователю число потоков и запускать и усыплять на определенное время, после чего выводить их в порядке того, как они просыпались: "Поток" + n + " отдыхал \"" + time + "\" мс";

```
public class Test {


    private static final int count = 5;

    public static CountDownLatch START = new CountDownLatch(count);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<NewThread> list = new ArrayList<NewThread>();

        long max = 0;
        long t = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            t = (long) (Math.random()*1000);
            list.add(new NewThread(String.valueOf(i), t));
            max = (max <= t) ? (max = t) : (max = max);
        }

        String s = null;

        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(max);
                System.out.println("Хотите протестировать еще раз?");
                System.out.println("Для продолжения введите \"Да\"");
                System.out.println("Для окончания введите любое другое сообщения");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                s = sc.nextLine();
                START = new CountDownLatch(count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    t = (long) (Math.random() * 1000);
                    list.get(i).rerun(t);
                    max = (max <= t) ? (max = t) : (max = max);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        while (s.equals("Да"));


    }

    public static class NewThread extends Thread{

        long time;
        String name;

        public NewThread(String name, long time){
            super(name);
            this.name = name;
            this.time = time;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){

            try {
                System.out.println("Поток " + name + " готов стартовать");
                START.countDown();

                START.await();

                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println("Поток " + name + " закончил отдых. Он отдыхал \"" + time +"\"");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void rerun(long time){

            try{
                System.out.println("Поток " + name + " готов отдыхать");
                START.countDown();

                START.await();

                Thread.sleep(time);
                System.out.println("Поток " + name + " закончил отдых. Он отдыхал \"" + time +"\"");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Помимо этого после выполнения программа должна спрашивать пользователя хочет ли он повторить прогон и делать тоже самое, только не создавая новых потоков, а используя уже существующие. С этим и возникает загвоздка, создание новых потоков у меня работает корректно, а вот использование уже существующих т.к. я использую метод `CountDownLatch await()` естественно зависает. Не приходит никакого решения в голову? Можете помочь?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять тактику: если нужно усыпить поток, заканчивайте его, если надо разбудить , создавайте новый....

Comment: у меня задача состоит в том, чтобы не убивать как раз потоки и не создавать новые, а использовать только существующие

Comment: В чем разница? Более понятно, если менеджер потоков будет просто считать запущенные потоки, нежели ему нужно оценивать статус потоков. Если вы всё поставите на паузу, то ресурсы системы будут отьедены и у вас точно начнуться проблемы с остановкой приложения.

Comment: Просто у меня задача в одновременном запуске потоков... При этом сами потоки создаются 1 раз. Далее просто должно начинаться все заново... Потоки перезапускаться не должны... вот я не совсем понимаю как это должно происходить

Comment: Почитайте здесь https://habr.com/ru/post/277669/

Comment: может речь идет о пуле потоков которые грызут параллельно задачи из общей очереди какой-то?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать поток несколько раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145763/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при окончании метода run(), поток умирает, стек и память сразу освобождаются, и не возможно запустить один поток несколько раз  -[Как использовать поток несколько раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145763/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)  , читайте.
Проще все будет после await() написать вызов функции в while() , в которую впихнуть вопрос к пользователю - повторить или нет создание новых потоков.Если да , то в этой же функции создать новые потоки и тд. И также создать переменную Boolean что бы она регулировала цикл while() в главном потоке

Comment: Надеюсь помог :)